# How to use Mathematica to solve this "simple" equation?

Tags: equation-solving

I tried to solve this equation using mathmatica 13.2 but failed. I'm a noob to *Mathematica*, is MMA able to solve this equation? Thank you!

(PS. How to show λ rather than \[Lambda] in forum? I just copy the code from .nb to the webpage and automatically show as \[Lambda])

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq = Arg[\[Lambda]/(E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)*(1 - (1 - \[Lambda])/E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)))] == \[Pi]/4;
Solve[eq, \[Omega], Assumptions -> {kf > 0, \[Lambda] > 0, \[Lambda] != 1, \[Omega] > 0, \[Omega] < 2*\[Pi]}]
```

Comment: SE Toolbar [post](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1043/additional-useful-buttons-for-our-m-se-editor) and [github link](https://github.com/halirutan/SE-Editor-Buttons).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eq = Arg[λ/(E^((I*ω)/kf)*(1 - (1 - λ)/E^((I*ω)/kf)))] == π/4;
```

Use [`ComplexExpand`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexExpand.html) to simplify the equation

```
eq2 = Assuming[{kf > 0, λ > 0, λ != 1, ω > 0, ω < 2*π},
  ComplexExpand[eq, TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}] // Simplify]

(* 4 ArcTan[-1 + λ + Cos[ω/kf], -Sin[ω/kf]] == π *)
```

**EDIT:** Removed Quiet to show warning messages

```
Column[sol = 
  Assuming[{kf > 0, λ > 0, λ != 1, ω > 0, ω < 2*π},
    SolveValues[eq2, ω, Reals, Method -> Reduce] //
     FullSimplify]]
```

[image]
[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[sol[[1]] /. C[1] -> 1], {λ, 10^-6, 3}, {kf, 10^-6, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

```
Plot3D[Evaluate[sol[[2]] /. C[1] -> 1], {λ, 15/8, 5/2}, {kf, 10^-6, 1},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 3,
 WorkingPrecision -> 15]
```

[image]

Comment: Why do you use `Quiet`? What error message is produced?

Comment: @user64494 - added warning messages

Answer (score 2):

This can be done as follows. First, we apply that `Arg[z]==Pi/4` is equivaletnt to `Re[z]==Im[z]&&Re[z]>=0`. Second, we obtain a polynomial equation instead of a trig equation. Hence,

```
eq1 = ComplexExpand[Re[\[Lambda]/(E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)*
(1 - (1 - \[Lambda])/E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)))]] == 
ComplexExpand[Im[\[Lambda]/(E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)*(1 - (1 - \[Lambda])/E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)))]];
Solve[kf > 0 && \[Lambda] > 0 && \[Lambda] != 1 && \[Omega] > 
 0 && \[Omega] < 2*\[Pi] && 1 == s^2 + t^2 && 
ComplexExpand[
  Re[\[Lambda]/(E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)*(1 - (1 - \[Lambda])/
         E^((I*\[Omega])/kf)))]] > 0 && 
eq1 /. {Sin[\[Omega]/kf] -> t, Cos[\[Omega]/kf] -> s}, {s, t}, Reals] // InputForm
```

> `{{s -> ConditionalExpression[ (1 - \[Lambda])/2 - Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/ 2, kf > 0 && Inequality[0, Less,  \[Omega], Less, 2*Pi] && Inequality[2,  Less, \[Lambda], Less,  Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 4, 0]]],  t -> ConditionalExpression[ -1/2*1/(-1 + \[Lambda]) +  Sqrt[(1 + 4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 + 8*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 - 4*\[Lambda]^2*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2)/(-1 + \[Lambda])^2]/2,  kf > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega],  Less, 2*Pi] && Inequality[2,  Less, \[Lambda], Less,  Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 4, 0]]]},  {s -> ConditionalExpression[ (1 - \[Lambda])/2 - Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/ 2, kf > 0 && Inequality[0, Less,  \[Omega], Less, 2*Pi] && Inequality[ Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 4, 0], Less, \[Lambda],  Less, 1 + Sqrt[2]]],  t -> ConditionalExpression[ -1/2*1/(-1 + \[Lambda]) -  Sqrt[(1 + 4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 + 8*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 - 4*\[Lambda]^2*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 -  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2)/(-1 + \[Lambda])^2]/2,  kf > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega],  Less, 2*Pi] && Inequality[ Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 4, 0], Less, \[Lambda],  Less, 1 + Sqrt[2]]]},  {s -> ConditionalExpression[ (1 - \[Lambda])/2 + Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/ 2, kf > 0 && Inequality[0, Less,  \[Omega], Less, 2*Pi] && Inequality[1,  Less, \[Lambda], Less,  Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 3, 0]]],  t -> ConditionalExpression[ -1/2*1/(-1 + \[Lambda]) +  Sqrt[(1 + 4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 + 8*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 - 4*\[Lambda]^2*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2)/(-1 + \[Lambda])^2]/2,  kf > 0 && Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega],  Less, 2*Pi] && Inequality[1,  Less, \[Lambda], Less,  Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 3, 0]]]},  {s -> ConditionalExpression[ (1 - \[Lambda])/2 + Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/ 2, (Inequality[0, Less, \[Lambda],  Less, 1] && Inequality[0, Less,  \[Omega], Less, 2*Pi] && kf > 0) ||  (Inequality[2, Less, \[Lambda], Less,  Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 4, 0]] &&  Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega], Less,  2*Pi] && kf > 0) ||  (Inequality[Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 -  8*#1^3 + 2*#1^4 & , 3, 0],  Less, \[Lambda], Less, 2] &&  Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega], Less,  2*Pi] && kf > 0) ||  (Inequality[Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 -  8*#1^3 + 2*#1^4 & , 4, 0],  Less, \[Lambda], Less, 1 + Sqrt[2]] &&  Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega], Less,  2*Pi] && kf > 0)],  t -> ConditionalExpression[ -1/2*1/(-1 + \[Lambda]) -  Sqrt[(1 + 4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2) -  4*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 + 8*\[Lambda]*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2 - 4*\[Lambda]^2*((1 - \[Lambda])/2 +  Sqrt[1 + 2*\[Lambda] - \[Lambda]^2]/2)^ 2)/(-1 + \[Lambda])^2]/2,  (Inequality[0, Less, \[Lambda], Less,  1] && Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega],  Less, 2*Pi] && kf > 0) ||  (Inequality[2, Less, \[Lambda], Less,  Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 - 8*#1^3 +  2*#1^4 & , 4, 0]] &&  Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega], Less,  2*Pi] && kf > 0) ||  (Inequality[Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 -  8*#1^3 + 2*#1^4 & , 3, 0],  Less, \[Lambda], Less, 2] &&  Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega], Less,  2*Pi] && kf > 0) ||  (Inequality[Root[-1 + 8*#1^2 -  8*#1^3 + 2*#1^4 & , 4, 0],  Less, \[Lambda], Less, 1 + Sqrt[2]] &&  Inequality[0, Less, \[Omega], Less,  2*Pi] && kf > 0)]}}`

I leave the rest on your own.